# Order by index unexpectedly slowing query down

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.3, index-tuning, query-performance

I have two tables: `houses` has ~415,000 records, and `account_houses` has ~525,000 records. I've changed the table names for security reasons, but basically I am using this query:

```
SELECT "houses".* FROM "houses"
  INNER JOIN "account_houses" ON "houses"."id" = "account_houses"."house_id"
  WHERE "account_houses"."account_id" = 123456
    AND "houses"."archived_at" IS NULL
  ORDER BY houses.mortgage_maturation_date DESC NULLS LAST,
           houses.id DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

My tables look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE account_houses (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    account_id integer,
    house_id integer
);

CREATE TABLE houses (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    mortgage_maturation_date date,
    archived_at timestamp without time zone
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY account_houses
  ADD CONSTRAINT account_houses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY houses
  ADD CONSTRAINT houses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX index_account_houses_on_account_id ON account_houses USING btree (account_id);

CREATE INDEX index_account_houses_on_house_id ON account_houses USING btree (house_id);
```

The query, as given, runs in around ~2,000ms with the above-two indices (when I restart postgres and purge the disk cache) which is rather unacceptable for a web application. In an attempt to optimize it, I've added the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX  "index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id" ON "houses"  ("mortgage_maturation_date" DESC NULLS LAST, "id" DESC)
```

Which... runs in 6,500ms, so significantly worse, for the same query.

IF I change the query by ONLY changing `DESC NULLS LAST` to `DESC`, as follows:

```
SELECT "houses".* FROM "houses"
  INNER JOIN "account_houses" ON "houses"."id" = "account_houses"."house_id"
  WHERE "account_houses"."account_id" = 123456
    AND "houses"."archived_at" IS NULL
  ORDER BY houses.mortgage_maturation_date DESC,
           houses.id DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

And change my last index to:

```
CREATE INDEX  "index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id" ON "houses"  ("mortgage_maturation_date" DESC, "id" DESC)
```

Then that specific query runs in 147ms, which is significantly improved. However, this means the ordering will be "wrong", because I really *do* want the `NULL` dates to be last in the returned results.

For the first query in this post, with the `DESC NULLS LAST` date index (that takes ~6500ms), the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, BUFFERS)` reads as follows:

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..7595.56 rows=30 width=342) (actual time=3070.894..6290.443 rows=30 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=294700 read=16715
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..1705519.95 rows=6737 width=342) (actual time=3070.893..6290.423 rows=30 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=294700 read=16715
        ->  Index Scan using index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id on houses  (cost=0.42..529696.79 rows=411714 width=342) (actual time=1.787..4351.319 rows=63312 loops=1)
              Filter: (archived_at IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 223
              Buffers: shared hit=44952 read=12594
        ->  Index Scan using index_account_houses_on_house_id on account_houses  (cost=0.42..2.85 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=63312)
              Index Cond: (house_id = houses.id)
              Filter: (account_id = 250753)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
              Buffers: shared hit=249748 read=4121
Total runtime: 6291.392 ms
```

So... is there anything I can do to make the `DESC NULLS LAST` order clause... faster?

#### Edit:

I dropped the order index and changed it to this (per comments):

```
CREATE INDEX index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id ON houses USING btree ((COALESCE(mortgage_maturation_date, '-infinity'::date)) DESC, id);
```

With the query using:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(houses.mortgage_maturation_date, '-infinity') DESC, 
         houses.id DESC
```

But the runtime is still ~2k ms. The explain on this new query shows a SORT operation though, and if the index were being used I don't think I would see that:

```
"  ->  Sort  (cost=39851.25..39868.09 rows=6737 width=342) (actual time=1890.597..1890.602 rows=30 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: (COALESCE(houses.mortgage_maturation_date, '-infinity'::date)), houses.id"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 39kB"
```

Did I do something wrong in the index definition or in my `ORDER BY` clause?

#### EDIT 2

(composite unique index on the `account_houses` table)

I made these index changes:

```
CREATE  INDEX  "index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id" ON "houses"  ("mortgage_maturation_date" DESC NULLS LAST, "id" DESC)
DROP INDEX "index_account_houses_on_house_id"
DROP INDEX "index_account_houses_on_account_id"
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_account_houses_on_house_id_and_account_id" ON "account_houses"  ("house_id", "account_id")
```

But the query was still ~5700ms, with this explain:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.85..7595.56 rows=30 width=342) (actual time=3046.307..5585.301 rows=30 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=233917 read=13791"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..1705519.95 rows=6737 width=342) (actual time=3046.306..5585.243 rows=30 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=233917 read=13791"
"        ->  Index Scan using index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id on houses  (cost=0.42..529696.79 rows=411714 width=342) (actual time=1.451..4735.182 rows=63312 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (archived_at IS NULL)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 223"
"              Buffers: shared hit=44962 read=12584"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using index_account_houses_on_house_id_and_account_id on account_houses  (cost=0.42..2.85 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=63312)"
"              Index Cond: ((house_id = houses.id) AND (account_id = 250753))"
"              Heap Fetches: 30"
"              Buffers: shared hit=188955 read=1207"
"Total runtime: 5586.164 ms"
```

#### EDIT 3

I tried another weird thing... an extension to the '-infinity' idea:

```
UPDATE houses SET mortgage_maturation_date='-infinity'::date
  WHERE mortgage_maturation_date IS NULL
```

And then the index:

```
CREATE  INDEX  "index_houses_on_mortgage_maturation_date_and_id" ON "houses"  ("mortgage_maturation_date" DESC, "id" DESC)
```

And the ORDER BY clause in my query:

```
ORDER BY houses.mortgage_maturation_date DESC, houses.id DESC
```

The query takes... 5200 ms.  Keep in mind that this is the EXACT SAME query above that ran in 147ms; Literally the only difference here is that I've updated all `null` `mortgage_maturation_date` columns to `-infinity` (that's 317,390 columns with a value that formerly had none, of 413,977 total records). I also tried this with the dual-composite-indices suggestion from the comments, but it produced no change (unique composite indexes on `account_id, house_id`, and `house_id, account_id`)

Comment: Did you try `order by coalesce(houses.mortgage_maturation_date, '-infinity') desc` and an index on the `coalesce()` expression?

Comment: Do the tables have no PRIMARY KEY? And no other indexes besides the two shown?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post to include the primary key definitions for the tables. There are also auto-incrementing sequence definitions for those PK columns if you want me to include that, wasn't sure it was necessary.

Comment: A composite index on `(account_id, house_id)` would be better I think for this query. You could even make it UNIQUE, if there is never a case of two rows for same account and house. Or even make it PRIMARY KEY and remove completely the `id` from that table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm unfamiliar with `'infinity'` in postgres - the way you've written it, that looks like a string, I'll see what happens...

Comment: But for the other table, probably a filtered index on: `(mortgage_maturation_date DESC NULLS LAST, id DESC) WHERE (archived_at IS NULL)` would benefit.

Comment: `'-infinity'` is a (date) value that is smaller than all others. It does work, I just don't know if it's faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be using my new index. Changes in post, let me know if I did something wrong there...

Comment: The cast to `::date` is not necessary, but if you include it in the index you should do that in the order by as well. Btw: which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres 9.3.4 - I didn't *manually* do the cast to `::date`, that was there when my framework (RoR) used pg_dump to dump the structure.sql file for me. The query I used was: `CREATE  INDEX  "index_court_cases_on_court_date_and_id" ON "court_cases"  (COALESCE(court_date, '-infinity') DESC, id)`.  Adding `::date` to the select query doesn't change the runtime.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I made a composite unique index (see EDIT 2 in post), but saw no real change to query execution time. This is one of the things I originally tried as well. I don't really want to make it a composite PK; and doing so wouldn't really affect this query anyway.

Comment: My suggestion was for an `(account_id, house_id)` index. You made the reverse one. It's **not** the same thing. But anyway, this may not help the actual issue much, only a little, Did you try my suggestion for the filtered index?

Comment: In a junction table, like the `account_houses`, I almost always have 2 (unique) indexes, one on `(a,b)` and another on `(b,a)`. They are useful in many queries, much more than the simple ones.

Comment: Woops! You're right I did do them in the wrong order; Earlier I tried a non-unique index in the `account_id, house_id` order you mentioned and it didn't help much. Also, I have tried that partial index you mentioned `where archived_at is null` before; the problem is, 95% of the records have a NULL `archived_at`, so it didn't really help much. (411,822 have null archived_at, out of 413,977 total records)

Comment: You show a primary key on `accounts`, a table not mentioned anywhere else in your question, and no primary key on `houses`.  And from the query plans, it sure looks like you don't have a primary key on `houses.id`.  Try adding one.